# c# Windows Azure Mobile Services insert/read data

Tags: c#, azure

I'm creating a Windows 8 Store App (c#) using Windows Azure Mobile Services to store my data.
I can successfully add data to the **Table (ToDoItem)** but got problems with reading it.

To add Data:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Private")]
    public bool Private { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "FirstTeam")]
    public string Team1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "SecondTeam")]
    public string Team2 { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class ViewItems : Page
{

    private ObservableCollection<TodoItem> items;
    private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();

    private async void InsertTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)
    {
        await todoTable.InsertAsync(todoItem);
    }

    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var todoItem = new TodoItem { Text = Ploeg1.Text, Team1 = Ploeg1.Text, Team2 = Ploeg2.Text};
        InsertTodoItem(todoItem);
    }
}
```

So this piece of code works! Now the problem: I want to read the data from the Mobile Service in **another** blank page:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Private")]
    public bool Private { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "FirstTeam")]
    public string Team1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "SecondTeam")]
    public string Team2 { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class gamestore : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<TodoItem> items;
    private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();

    private void ButtonRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       RefreshTodoItems();
    }

    private async void RefreshTodoItems()
    {
        var results = await todoTable2
            .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Private == false)
            .ToListAsync();

        items = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>(results);
        ListItems.ItemsSource = items;
    }
}
```

I have some Ambiguity errors with this. I know I'm using the same names but those are my column names. How can I make this work so it would be able to read the saved data on another page??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed the problem! Changed a few names

Comment: A few column names or what did you change?